# Как лучше задать метод?

Tags: java

В чём разница между `v` и `view`? Как лучше?

```
public void сlear1 (View v) {
        tvKof.setText("0");       
    }


public void сlear1 (View view) {
        tvKof.setText("0");       
    }
```

Comment: Ни там, ни там, параметр не используется.

Comment: @Kromster странно, почему этот вопрос еще не закрыт? 1)Он слишком общий 2)Это странный вопрос, как будто человек не знает язык и наткнулся на код в первый раз 3)Ну и на крайний случай он гуглится по запросу "good code style java"

Comment: @AntonSorokin, не вижу твоего голоса за закрытие

Comment: @Grundy а он есть

Comment: это просто ИМЯ .. какое имя переменной вам удобнее использовать, то и используйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разницы нету.

Если в большом методе будет много переменных с таким кратким названием как `v`, код утратит свою читабельность, и возможно будет не понятно за что переменная отвечает.

Так же при вызове метода в другом участке кода, в IDEA при нажатии `Сtrl + P` будет подсвечиваться как и объект (что лежит в сигнатуре метода) так и его название.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]